# MailJs help, Unable to check new messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, email, gmail

so I am trying to make a that creates an email and waits for a email i've dones some of the steps but! i am having trouble using the GetMessages function.

```
mailjs.getMessages()
.then(res => {
     console.log(res.data)
})
```

as its returning either nothing or just giving an error and i know for a fact that its not the email coming in late as i have a ten second delay which is way longer then what is needed.

most of  time with i try to get the id it will return "[]" but when i just console.log(res) i can see the email came in?

before you ask i am already logged in and have been able to regiser / login to the account.

Comment: * I am logged in using the cretaeoneaccount function and have been able to see the message come in but have never been able to get the id I still need help

Comment: still need help.